# Why does using openvpn as usual do not work anymore on my Unbuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, openvpn

I installed openvpn on my computer (Ubuntu 18.04) last week and it has been working fine until today.
When i started my computer this morning and typed the following command:
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
I got:

```
ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eno1 HWADDR=00:4e:01:aa:62:bd
TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
/sbin/ip route add 164.177.32.73/32 via 192.168.1.1
/sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.0.2
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
/sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.0.2
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
/sbin/ip route add 128.47.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.30
Nexthop has invalid gateway.
ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

I couldn't figured out what's wrong since i did nothing special to my computer.
Here is my conf file: client.ovpn

```
##############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
dev tap
;dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote 164.177.32.73 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
#user nobody
#group nobody

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
#ca ca.crt
#cert client1.crt
#key client1.key
pkcs12 my-vpn.p12

# Verify server certificate by checking that the
# certicate has the correct key usage set.
# This is an important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the keyUsage set to
#   digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
# and the extendedKeyUsage to
#   serverAuth
# EasyRSA can do this for you.
#remote-cert-tls server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
tls-auth ta.key 1

key-direction 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
;cipher x

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

Do you have any idea about this issue?
I have to say my coworker is also working on linux and fixed the issue by adding comment # to "group nobody" "user nobody". It didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out!! We discovered that me and the coworker couldn't use same key and conf at the same time (I can't say why it was working the week before that). I created a new key thanks to the following command: 
openvpn --genkey --secret taa.key
And replaced ta.key with taa.key in the client.ovpn file.
That's it!